# Netsuite, Image within Salesorders

Tags: netsuite

Good day all,

Just a question, we are a new company that have started using NetSuite. When we was original sold the product we was promised the world but ... that hasn't really happened.

My question seems an easy one but I cant get my head around it, is there any way images can be added to sales orders that will be able to be seen on purchase orders, delivery notes etc.

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Hi Lee, you will find with NS there is a lot you can do if you either have the skillset or can work with a company who does.

Images can be easy enough. This can be done a few different ways. What kind of image do you mean? Is this a company logo? Or is this something that could change per transaction or customer?

Comment: Ok, so best way to explain is that we are using it as our selling software for our showrooms, we sell Bathroom equipment. What I  want to do is add a prodect for example L/Hand shower tray, and that has an image attached to it that will print on all documents EG SO, Delivery Notes, Returns / Bills. I have seen that images can be added but from what I can see this relates to websites. Sorry if this seems confusing, trying to find the best way to explain.

Comment: that makes sense. Do you want this on a line item level then for these transactions? I see a header (body) level field type for image but it seems you need line level for this.

Comment: Yes I would need this to be on a line item level. there are about 8 diiferent images I would need to create, the idea is that a code " Pic-L/Hand shower tray" as a non inventory item would be used. This is so the sales reps can add these images to So's where needed.

Comment: Ideally when adding a item on the system as a non inventory item a field that allows images to be copied would be great, this is how an old system we used worked but unless I'm going mad there doesn't seem to be this option within NetSuite.

Comment: I will see what I can do in our sandbox. If anyone else has an idea, please advise. I'll get back to you if I find a way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the Advanced XML/PDF template option you can easily add an image to your printed/emailed documents. If you are not using a website remember the image has to be at a publicly reachable location.

In the line item section you can reference the line item's item fields like:

```
<td align="right" colspan="4"><img src="${item.item.storedisplaythumbnail}" /></td>
```

note the item.item. The first item comes from the variable name you give in the transaction's line item iteration tag. The second one must be 'item'