# Print image field in advanced pdf/html

Tags: netsuite

I want to print an image field which is a signature on employee record.`${entity.custbody_signature}`
But when I print it is showing as '?' in the print.
This advanced pdf/html template is on purchase order record.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810238/netsuite-image-within-salesorders

Comment: You may need to check that the image is available without login in the file cabinet\

Comment: yes. it is available w/o login

Answer (score 1):

I created a free-form-text field on PO to store image file url in it. And then printed that image this way in the advanced pdf :

```
<img src= "${record.imgfieldname}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use <@filecabinet nstype="image" src="${entity.custbody_signature}">.
You won't need to use "available without login"

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the image url from image field in NetSuite is to do something like this

```
<img src= "${record.custbody_signature@Url}"/>
```